# Move "I am vendor" and "I am customer" at the top of the form before other fields in Dokan

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, dokan

how set "I am vendor" and "I am customer" on dokan plugin at the top of form before all other fields?

[image]

I already moved this codes to other places of the "seller-registeration-form.php":

```
<?php do_action( 'dokan_reg_form_field' ); ?>


<p class="form-row form-group user-role vendor-customer-registration">

    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="role" value="customer"<?php checked( $role, 'customer' ); ?> class="dokan-role-customer">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'I am a customer', 'dokan-lite' ); ?>
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="role" value="seller"<?php checked( $role, 'seller' ); ?>  class="dokan-role-seller">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'I am a supplier', 'dokan-lite' ); ?>
    </label>
    <?php do_action( 'dokan_registration_form_role', $role ); ?>
</p>
```

but it didn't work !

can any one help me please?